# How to run the cucumber test using gradle

Tags: java, cucumber-jvm

I'm having trouble running Cucumber tests in Gradle. I am using cucumber-jvm.

Class `TestNGCucumberRunner` extends the `AbstractTestNGCucumberTests` and testng annotations with `@beforesuite`, `@aftersuite`..

I usually run the `TestNGCucumberRunner.java` in IntelliJ by right-click and it runs successfully.  Now I want to

1. Invoke the TestNGCucumberRunner.java in gradle

or

2. Invoke all the features in gradle

I tried to execute the TestNGCucumberRunner.java as a javaexec but that fails.

I tried to execute all the feature files in the package. I have used `apply plugin: 'com.github.samueltbrown.cucumber'` also.

Comment: Below is the project structure                                                                               This is the folder structure where the scripts
     src-test-java-ctest-sampletest,TestNGCucumberRunner
     src-test-java-cpage-loginpage
     src-test-resources-navigation.feature

Comment: Could you edit and post some of your build.gradle file?

Comment: Have you had a look at this https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/examples/java-gradle/build.gradle

Comment: Thanks for the reply :), I have extracted the above examples and it is working fine and will implement the same from the start.I will do it and let you know the result .Thanks once again

Comment: @user3350712 : HI, Your question on running through Cucumber runner through gradle is very interesting. Just wanted to know and checkby if you were able to crack the solution for our query ? If yes  then i am curious to know and see your build.gradle  file. Can you share the same i will give a try from my end and keep you updated of my findings.

Comment: @judoole : Hi , Can you please post the working link  of github " github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/examples/"  related gradle cucumber-JVM even i more interested to have a look. just check the link is not working throwing 404.

Comment: @balaji-singh-y Seems like the example disappeared at version 4. This should still have some code in it https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/v3.0.2/examples/java-gradle

Answer (score 9):

### **UPDATE:**

My **new** setup uses a different [plugin](https://github.com/commercehub-oss/gradle-cucumber-jvm-plugin) that supports parallel execution of scenarios, better reporting, and is still actively maintained:

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
  ...
  id "com.commercehub.cucumber-jvm" version "0.11"
}

addCucumberSuite 'cucumberTest'

dependencies {
  ...
  cucumberTestCompile 'info.cukes:cucumber-java:1.2.5'  // or -java8 if you prefer lambda notation

}
```

**directory structure**:

```
└── src
    ├── cucumberTest
    │   ├── java
    │   │   └── package1 
    │           └──       <- Glue
    │   └── resources    
    │       └── package2 
    │           └──       <- Features
    ├── main
    │   └── java
    └── test
        └── java
```

*package1* and *package2* names (together with many other [options](https://github.com/commercehub-oss/gradle-cucumber-jvm-plugin#cucumber-task-configuration)) can be specified in the build.gradle file

---

### OLD

My **previous** setup for using cucumber for java with gradle.

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id "java"
    id "com.github.samueltbrown.cucumber" version "0.9"
  }   

dependencies {
    cucumberCompile 'info.cukes:cucumber-java:1.2.4'
}

cucumber {
    formats = ['pretty','junit:build/cucumber.xml']
}
```

**Directory layout**

```
└── src
    ├── cucumber
    │   ├── java         <- Glue
    │   └── resources    <- Features
    └── main
    │    └── java
    └── test
        └── java
```

**Command**

```
gradle cucumber
```

Answer (score 6):

I opted for not using `com.github.samueltbrown.cucumber`plugin, it was last updated in Aug 2015. Instead I created a "integrationTest" (cucumber) sourceSet that I can build independently. I.e, a simple `gradle build` will build `test` and `integrationTest` source sets. If I only want to run integration tests I can run `gradle integrationTest -x test`, or I can run only test with `gradle test -x integrationTest`.

The steps I followed are here: http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/gradle/getting-started-with-gradle-integration-testing/

But here is the summary:

build.gradle

```
sourceSets {
    integrationTest {
        java {
            compileClasspath += main.output + test.output
            runtimeClasspath += main.output + test.output
            srcDir file('src/integrationTest/java')
        }
        resources.srcDir file('src/integrationTest/resources')
    }
}

//Ensure that the integrationTestCompile/integrationTestRuntime configuration contains the dependencies that are required to compile/run our unit tests.
configurations {
    integrationTestCompile.extendsFrom testCompile
    integrationTestRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime
}

task integrationTest(type: Test) {
    testClassesDir = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDir
    classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath

    // Gradle skips tasks whose input and output are up to date.
    // To ensure that your integration tests are run every time,
    // tell Gradle that the outputs of the integrationTest task should always be considered out of date.
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
}

// Ensure that our integration tests are run before the check task and that the check task fails the build if there are failing integration tests.
// Ensure that our unit tests are run before our integration tests. This guarantees that our unit tests are run even if our integration tests fails.
check.dependsOn integrationTest
integrationTest.mustRunAfter test

// Ensure that the HTML reports of unit and integration tests are created to different report
// build/reports/integrationTest directory contains the HTML report that contains the test results of our integration tests.
tasks.withType(Test) {
    reports.html.destination = file("${reporting.baseDir}/${name}")
}

def cucumberVersion = "1.2.4"

dependencies {
    integrationTestCompile(
            'info.cukes:cucumber-core:' + cucumberVersion,
            'info.cukes:cucumber-java:' + cucumberVersion,
            'info.cukes:cucumber-java:' + cucumberVersion,
            'info.cukes:cucumber-junit:' + cucumberVersion,
            'info.cukes:cucumber-spring:' + cucumberVersion,
            'org.springframework:spring-beans:4.2.5.RELEASE'
    )
    integrationTestRuntime(
            'org.springframework:spring-context:4.2.5.RELEASE',
            'org.springframework:spring-test:4.2.5.RELEASE',
            'org.springframework:spring-tx:4.2.5.RELEASE'
    )
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The cucumber docs do not use the gradle Test task type, so certain integrations are not there (notably Jacoco).  Im still hunting for a way to get a Test task to execute cucumbers main when it runs tests.